# NodeJS plugin fail to build in Sublime Text 3 saying "Error: Cannot find module '/Volumes/Macintosh'"

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3

I downloaded NodeJS plugin using Package Control in Sublime Text 3.

When I build a sample nodeJS file, it prompts me the following error:

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Volumes/Macintosh'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3 
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1] 
[shell_cmd: killall node; /usr/bin/env node /Volumes/Macintosh HD/xxx/Documents/nodejs/node-tutorial/nodemailer.js] 
[dir: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/xxx/Documents/nodejs/node-tutorial] 
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin]
```

Upon initial inspection, I think it has to do with my volume name being `Macintosh HD` with a space  and NodeJS compiler somehow ignored the space.

I want to know what caused this and how to fix it, please?

Answer (score 0):

This recently happens to me when I updated Sublime Text 3. The build system fails as the filepath contains spaces. I edit my original **Node.sublime-build** from:

```
{
  "shell_cmd": "node ${file}",
  "selector" : "source.js",
}
```

to:

```
{
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "selector" : "source.js"
}
```

And everything works fine again.